# How to set the physical size of PDF pages with Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, eps

I want to convert a bunch of .eps images to a single PDF using Ghostscript.

But when I look at the PDF file in a PDF viewer and set view to 100% to physical size of the file is huge!

I would like to force gs to create the PDF in letter size, but everything I tried failed. 
Here's the command I'm using:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSFitPage -dEPSCrop \
   -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf \
    file1.eps file2.eps
```

All my attempts with `-sPAPERSIZE=legal` and `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=w -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=h` had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `-dEPSFitPage` it was fitting the page size to the .eps file size... using `-dPDFFitPage` (and skipping the mutually exclusive `-dEPSCrop`) solved my problem.

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=letter \
   -dPDFFitPage -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=out.pdf \
    file1.eps file2.eps
```

Answer (score 4):

`-dEPSFitPage` and `-dEPSCrop` are mutually exclusive.  Try getting rid of the `-dEPSCrop` and putting back `-sPAPERSIZE=legal`.  If that doesn't work, it is probably because the .eps file is over-riding the media, so try adding `-dFIXEDMEDIA`.

BTW, this answer is cribbed from:
[Fit to page size in ghostscript (with a possibly corrupt input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141412/fit-to-page-size-in-ghostscript-with-a-possibly-corrupt-input)

Comment: I tried to replace -dEPSCrop with -sPAPERSIZE=legal but same thing. doing identify -verbose out.pdf I see: Print size: 23.6111x30.5556

Comment: Adding -dFIXEDMEDIA I only see the bottom left corner on the page.